# Electron spin resonance

Tags: electrons, quantum-spin, resonance

What is the principle of electron spin resonance?
I'm performing an experiment in which I've a DPPH(paramagnetic) sample and I'm trying to find out the lande's factor using ESR setup. 
My problem is I'm not understanding the reason for getting two peaks on CRO screen.

Comment: Proton hyperfine structure?